# How to get the first item in a group by that meets a certain condition in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
grouped_stats = stats.groupby( stats.last_mv.ne( stats.last_mv.shift()).cumsum() )
```

last_mv is a decimal value
In the code above I am grouping by consecutive values

I am trying two ways to obtain the first value that is 0.25% above the first item in the groups last_mv value. In other words, I have grouped by consecutive last_mv values, I want to select the first of each group, multiply by 1.025 and then find the first value within the group that matches this value (if one exists)

I tried:

```
grouped_stats.filter(lambda x: x.last_mv >= (x.first().last_mv * 1.025))
```

but I can't access the first row in the group with .first() as I assumed I wouldnt

I also tried

```
grouped_stats.loc[ grouped_stats.last_mv >= (grouped_stats.first().last_mv * 1.025) ]
```

but I get the error: "Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Could you please mention sample input and expected sample output in code tags and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame` filled by first values per groups:

```
stats[ stats.last_mv >= (grouped_stats.last_mv.transform('first') * 1.025) ]
```

Comment: I get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." because grouped_stats.last_mv still returns "<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x0000020D1DF6EB00>"

Comment: @user2330270 - How working `grouped_stats.last_mv.transform('first')` ?

Comment: I mean for the bit before the condition >= .....
grouped_stats.last_mv.transform('first') correctly returns the first item of each group